# angular 5 i18n translate 403

Tags: angular, internationalization, angular5, angular-i18n

I'm trying to use i18n to make a multi-language website, but, while compiling the final version to the server, it is returning the error below.

can you help me?

[image]

My code [image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the endpoint you query does not return a `.json` file but rather an html error page (403 - forbidden).
Make sure you place the json files containing your translations at

`http://alertweb.com.br/develop/alertweb/assets/i18n/` so that you can query them correctly.

You simply moved your translation files to the wrong folder.